# Retrieve column values of the selected row of a multicolumn Access listbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

How can I retrieve the value of specified column of the selected row in a multicolumn listbox?

I populate the listbox by setting the RowSource property with a SQL string. BoundColumn set to value 1.

I can retrieve the value of the bound column (of the selected row) by using `ListBox.Value`. But I also want the value of another column.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `listboxControl.Column(intColumn,intRow)`. Both Column and Row are zero-based.

Comment: I think you need to beef that up a little to get currently selected items in a multiselect list box, say: `For Each itm In Me.List0.ItemsSelected` ..
    `s = s & vbCrLf & Me.List0.Column(1, itm)` ..
`Next` ..
`MsgBox s`

Comment: @Remou--you're absolutely correct. In fact, the code in my current project does exactly that--but the OP's question used the definite article, which I read as implying one selected row. Also--I'm sure you know this, but for anyone else reading, keep in mind that `itm` in your example must be `Variant`.

Comment: Yes, I meant one selected row, so `listboxControl.Column(intColumn)` works fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Just a little addition.
If you've only selected 1 row then the code below will select the value of a column (index of 4, but 5th column) for the selected row:

```
me.lstIssues.Column(4)
```

This saves having to use the ItemsSelected property.

Kristian

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the perfect code if you are looking for Current Selected row in ListBox. +1

Answer (score 2):

For multicolumn listbox extract data from any column of selected row by

```
 listboxControl.List(listboxControl.ListIndex,col_num)
```

where col_num is required column ( 0 for first column)

Comment: I think you meant listboxControl.Column(col_num, listboxControl.ListIndex)