# How do I reference a value from a list box in Column(0) on click?

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have a list box that is populated based on a previous filter (a text box). This means there is no predefined number of items in the listbox so using the index is impossible.

What I am looking for is a way of selecting the value of column(0), as there are 3 columns in my list box, of the selected line that is clicked.

```
Private Sub listSource_Click()

Dim strSource As String

strSource = "SELECT [Product Code],[Stock Level],[Description] FROM [products/stock] " & _
"WHERE Mid([Product Code],1,5) = " & Me.listSource.Column(0).Value & ";"

Me.listResult.RowSource = strSource
Me.listResult = vbNullString

End Sub
```

What I think I need is just the small piece of code that is supposed to be where "Me.listSource.Column(0).Value" is.

Thanks in advance,
Bob P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon you want:

```
strSource = "SELECT [Product Code],[Stock Level],[Description] " & _
"FROM [products/stock] " & _
"WHERE Mid([Product Code],1,5) = '" & Me.listSource & "';"
```

Note the single quotes before and after Me.listSource.

Comment: Mate, your a king. Thanks to everyone who had a go! But this sorted it.

Answer (score 1):

`Me.listresult` gives the bound column

you then have to append `.Column(0)`,`.Column(1)` ... for other columns.

to find out which one of the list you need to be looking at, `.ItemsSelected.Count` will tell you how many are selected (1 for a simple list box), and `.ItemsSelected(0)` for the index to the first item selected, so, the complete line for the first column of the first selected line would be:

```
Me.listSource.ItemData(Me.ListSource.ItemsSelected(0))
```

Comment: A quibble: Column(0) is only the default value if the bound column is 1.

Comment: @Remou, fixed. sloppy programming... having a bound column other than 1 never occured to me

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Me.ListSource.Column(0) to get the value of the first column of the selected row.

Also see: [Retrieve column values of the selected row of a multicolumn Access listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649000/retrieve-column-values-of-the-selected-row-of-a-multicolumn-access-listbox)

Comment: Still not working guys, here is the code I am using.

strSource = "SELECT [Product Code],[Stock Level],[Description] FROM [products/stock] " & _
"WHERE Mid([Product Code],1,5) = Mid(" & Me.listSource.Column(0) & ",1,5);"