# passing value of listfield to textfield

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im looking for a way to pass the values from my listfield to a textfield.

The listfield looks like this:

```
SID       HID         CENTRAL          DATE            TIME

ABC       AB          YES              15.02.2017      15:00
DEF       DE          NO               15.02.2017      17:00
...       ..          ..               ..........      .....
```

Is there any way to pass a value of the selected entry into a textfield? 
I need to pass the `HID` value of the selected entry into a textfield of my form.

if i select the first entry "`AB`" should be send the value to the textfield "`hid2`"

Comment: This should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649000/retrieve-column-values-of-the-selected-row-of-a-multicolumn-access-listbox  You might have more google success by search for listbox, not listfield.

Comment: LIST and LISTINDEX will assist you.  But for a listbox as Minty says.