# For Loop through a list box

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hope you can help - I have simple list box which is populated from DB and has 6 columns [ID, name, ordnumber, data, price ,postcode]

The listbox is populated without issues [So for that purposes I will not post the code]

The issue i have is when i'm trying to get the running total of the prices when I select item in list box.

```
 With lstOrdersInBatch
   tbxTotal.value = 0
    For IntIndex = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(IntIndex) Then
         'tbxTotal = tbxTotal + .Column(4)
   
           
        End If

    Next
End With
```

It's giving me incorrect value

I have gone through the debug log and it's seems it only take the last item selected & not all selected.

Hope you can help.

Thanks

Please note is access VBA programming.

===== SOLVED ===

[Retrieve column values of the selected row of a multicolumn Access listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649000/retrieve-column-values-of-the-selected-row-of-a-multicolumn-access-listbox)

That has the answer.

```
       With lstOrdersInBatch
       tbxTotal.value = 0
       For IntIndex = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(IntIndex) Then
            tbxTotal = tbxTotal + lstOrdersInBatch.Column(4, IntIndex)
            End If
    
       Next
   End With
```

Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've adjusted the code based on your comment:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To Me.lstOrdersInBatch.ListCount - 1
    If Me.lstOrdersInBatch.Selected(i) Then
        tbxTotal = tbxTotal + Me.lstOrdersInBatch.ItemData(i)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks Winter, however - i made silly mistake and didn't report that this is access VBA programming - as ListItem is not picked up by access :(

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the number of iterations and avoid the need for the `if` statement using the following:

```
Dim idx
tbxTotal = 0
With lstOrdersInBatch
    For Each idx In .ItemsSelected
        tbxTotal = tbxTotal + .Column(4, idx)
    Next idx
End With
```